# specify masterpage of subdirectory pages in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, master-pages

I know its possible to specify the masterpage of all pages using the pages element of the web.config but is it possible to specify that for all the pages under /foo/ that they should have a certain master page, and specify this in the root web.config.

I know this can probably be achieved by putting another web.config in the subdirectories that I want that specific masterpage to override but if possible I'd like to keep all of it in the one spot as when we change one section master page we are most likely going to be changing a few of them.

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understanding your aim but you can add a location elemenet in the root web.config file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Comment: hmm looks like it might work will give it a go...submit it as an answer so I can give you points if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add location element in the roor web config file with configuration specific for the subdirectory. [location Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx)

Comment: Yay Microsoft (sarcasm). Topic is no longer available. That sucks!